# Authenticate in Angular 2 with Digest authentication

Tags: angular, http-headers, ionic2, digest-authentication

I'm starting an *ionic-angular 2* application and I need to login to a server that uses **Digest authentication.**

Anyone knows how to do this? I'm stuck trying to retrieve the WWW-Authenticate header and I cant find any 3rd party library that works with angular 2.

Thanks!